# Active Directory implementation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, active-directory

we have authetication as file system in our application server.  Now i am trying to implement AD support into existing authentication within our application server, we need to add multiple AD support,

scenario
[image: Scenario]

so i added an application to configure the multiple LDAP, now i found that login to server will be based on DN, so i expect that user should know the base DN,

but how people will know base DN.

i can provide more detail if needed.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: I have done code in C++ using LDAP API, so to give an idea i tag it to C++ also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're dealing with AD, you can simply bind with the sAMAccountName or UPN. Alternatively, you can use a hard coded account to search the user with (e.g. `(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=%s))`) and get the DN from there.

With both options, the user don't have to type in (or even know) their DN.

Comment: thanks for input... first i must explain you the situation ... i already implemented all work to support AD in my server... question arises from client ... why should i remeber my base DN and my DN for assigning permission to user. as i explined in my prev communication  that user and password will be used to configure the LDAP server. so as per my understanding we need to DN for login into the AD servers.. it may be the case that my system is not on that particular domain... so i need to bind via user name and password.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you need a DN for the authenticating user or for something else?

Comment: yes i need DN from ldap server , but how can i get DN without authentication from ldap server using search

Comment: I'm still not sure I'm following, but if you need the user's DN, then simply use some pre-configured account and search using the query I wrote above

Comment: thanks .... but how i know the pre configured account as someone has to configured

Comment: That depends on your application deployment scenario, if you're only deploying it once, then I assume you have access to such an account, and if it's being used by many customers, then you can ask for this account as part of your setup. Also note that as I wrote in my original answer, you can also bind using the sam account name or UPN. You don't necessarily need the DN

Comment: thanks.... yes it will be used by many customer ....  so it would good if you will provide more detail about UPN and sam account name ...how to use ???

Comment: That depends on the library you use, but you can just pass the UPN or sam account name to bind.

Comment: i am using MFC c++ library
 int main()
 {
  LDAP *ld;

  char *ldap_host = "10.96.11.89";
  int ldap_port   = 389;
  int auth_method = LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE;
  int desired_version = LDAP_VERSION3;
  char *root_dn   = "CN=Admin,OU=Users,O=MYO";
  char *root_ps   = "1";

  int rc;

  ld = ldap_init(ldap_host,ldap_port);

  rc = ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &desired_version);

  rc = ldap_bind_s(ld, root_dn, root_ps, auth_method);

  if(rc != LDAP_SUCCESS ) return 0;

  return 1;
 }

Comment: I have no experience with this library, but in general AD allows you to specify a UPN or sam account name instead of the user's DN when binding. I would guess that in this case you would use either of them instead of the root_dn